# log out and back button

Tags: asp.net

I'm using Forms authentication. I have a small problem after the user logs out. If he hits the back button after he logs out, he's sent to the page he was on when he was logged in.

What is the best way to prevent that? I've looked around but it doesn't seem that there's one definitive approach. Ideally, I'm thinking I'd like to have a function on the master page or even in an httpmodule that checks to see if the user is logged in and if not, redirect him to the login. Is that the best way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you do `Session.Abandon()` and `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()` on your `Logout` page it doesn't matter whether the user can go back to the previous page he was in, the moment he clicks on anything will be redirected to the `Login` page.

Example:

Page_Load login/logout page:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
       FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
       Session.Abandon();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may turn of the [cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.cache%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) ability of restricted pages by adding following statement in `page_load` event.

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the Back button in the browser is not controllable by ASP.NET (at least not in a way to disable it), I suggest that you do it like you suggested:

On every page, check to see whether the user is logged in, if not, redirect him to the login page, optionally with a `goto` parameter to redirect him back to the page he wants to navigate to after successfully being logged in.

I do it this way, too for most of our applications.

Comment: How do you check if he's authenticated?

Comment: How do you check if he's authenticated? I use HttpApplication MyApp = ... and then HttpRequest MyRequest = ... and when I do if (MyRequest.IsAuthenticated == false) I always get false, even after the user is logged in.

Comment: @frenchie Since I've never used Forms Authentication, and always did my own authentication, I simple set a session variable upon successful login.

Answer (score 0):

HttpContext.User has the IsAuthenticated property for you to check in every page. If you really want to use your custom session variable make sure you remove it or do Session.Abandon at logout and check for it in All pages anyway.